# Cannot inject providers into Karma test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to inject the $urlRouterProvider into my tests but I keep getting the unknown provider issue. I'm using ui.router and testing directives and need to be able to get access to these provider, or all the tests fail...

**navbar.spec.js**

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: nav-bar', function () {

  beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
  beforeEach(module('ngMock'));
  beforeEach(module('kitchenapp'));


  var $httpBackend,
    $templateCache,
    $compile,
    $urlRouterProvider,
    $scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _$templateCache_, _$compile_, _$urlRouterProvider_) {


    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $templateCache = _$templateCache_;
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $urlRouterProvider = _$urlRouterProvider_;

    $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();

    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<nav-bar></nav-bar>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    $rootScope.$$phase || $rootScope.$apply();


  }));

  afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('\'s brand link should be titled \'KitchenApp\' and should navigate to the root address when clicked', function () {

    expect(2).toEqual(2);

  });


});
```

**Karma.conf.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: 'client',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      stripPrefix: 'client/',
      moduleName: 'templates'
    },

    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
    ],

    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.min.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'bower_components/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/js/angular-bootstrap-calendar-tpls.js',
      'app.js',
      'views/**/*.js',
      'services/**/*.js',
      'directives/**/*.js',
      'directives/**/*.html'
    ],

    exclude: [
      'views/**/*.e2e.js',
      'services/socket/socket.service.js'
    ],

    reporters: ['progress'],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    // possible values:
    // config.LOG_DISABLE
    // config.LOG_ERROR
    // config.LOG_WARN
    // config.LOG_INFO
    // config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: false,

    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('kitchenapp', [
  //Native services
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngTouch',

  //3rd party
  'btford.socket-io',
  'ui.router',
  'ui.grid',
  'mwl.calendar',
  'ui.bootstrap'
])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, calendarConfigProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

    calendarConfigProvider.configureDateFormats({
      hour: 'HH:mm' //this will configure the hour view to display in 24 hour format rather than the default of 12 hour
    });

    calendarConfigProvider.configureTitleFormats({
      day: 'ddd D MMM' //this will configure the day view title to be shorter
    });

  })
  .factory('authInterceptor',
  function ($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
    return {

      request: function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
        }
        return config;
      },

      responseError: function (response) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
          $location.path('/login');
          $cookieStore.remove('token');
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else {
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      }

    };
  })

  .run(function ($rootScope, $state, Auth) {

    $rootScope.Auth = Auth;
    //$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));

  });
```

**Error**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $urlRouterProviderProvider <- $urlRouterProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24urlRouterProviderProvider%20%3C-%20%24urlRouterProvider
    at /Users/jamessherry/sites/kitchenappFull/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4015
    at getService (/Users/jamessherry/sites/kitchenappFull/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4162)
    at /Users/jamessherry/sites/kitchenappFull/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4020
    at getService (/Users/jamessherry/sites/kitchenappFull/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4162)
    at invoke (/Users/jamessherry/sites/kitchenappFull/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4194)
    at workFn (/Users/jamessherry/sites/kitchenappFull/client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2436)
undefined
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation')
    at /Users/jamessherry/sites/kitchenappFull/client/directives/nav-bar/nav-bar.spec.js:34
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

**EDIT**
The issue occurs as soon as the provider injection is requested in the inject arguments; I suspect that's why the $httpBackend is not present, as it crashes at that point...

Comment: have you tried moving angular mocks up in the karma files list?  Perhaps it should be loaded before ui-router.

Comment: Hi @DavinTryon, I've tried playing around with the order but to no avail... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it transpires that you can't inject '$urlRouterProvider' into a function and expect the $injector to find it. i.e. this won't work:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
```

Instead, you have to do it using module, like so:

```
beforeEach(module(function($urlRouterProvider) {
      console.log('in', $urlRouterProvider);
      $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks, changed "inject" to "module" fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript version of this is:

```
beforeEach(this.module(function ($urlRouterProvider: angular.ui.IUrlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept(); 
}));
```

The "`this.`" in front of `module`is required.

It also must come before any `beforeEach(inject(` lines.